# Assign values to pandas column based on the index of the groupby operation

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like so:

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
tf = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': [1,2,3,2,2,3],
                   'data2': rng.randint(0, 10, 6)},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])
tf


   key  data1   data2
0   A   1   5
1   B   2   0
2   C   3   3
3   A   2   3
4   B   2   7
5   C   3   9
```

If I have an array `x = np.arange(4)` which is the same length as the number of groups in column ['key', 'data1'].

```
grouped = tf.groupby(['key', 'data1'])
print(grouped.get_group(('A', 1)), '\n')
print(grouped.get_group(('A', 2)), '\n')
print(grouped.get_group(('B', 2)), '\n')
print(grouped.get_group(('C', 3)), '\n')

 key  data1  data2
0   A      1      5 

  key  data1  data2
3   A      2      3 

  key  data1  data2
1   B      2      0
4   B      2      7 

  key  data1  data2
2   C      3      3
5   C      3      9
```

Now, there are 4 groups and I have a vector 'x' of length 4. I would like to assign x[i] to all rows of data2 for the i'th group, and I want to do this for all rows of the data frame. I was experimenting with apply(), but couldn't get too far. I finally found a way of doing it with loops and masks, but that is very slow when dealing with a large dataframe. Can anyone point out the correct way of doing this?

Comment: PS: the order of groups matter, so that the correct value of 'x' get's assigned the groups in the order as found in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed a solution which is way faster than with masks. This works for me for now.

```
unique_groups=tf.loc[:,"key":"data1"].drop_duplicates(
                                          subset['key','data1']).values
grouped = tf.groupby(['key', 'data1'])
for i in range(len(unique_groups)):
    tf.loc[grouped.get_group(tuple(unique_groups[i])).index, 'data2'] = x[i]
```

But this still has loops, and still does take more time than any native pandas function. Is there a native pandas way to do this?